# Multiple foreach replacement

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

I have a function which writes text on a picturebox using the string it received from a list, and the X and Y coordinates of Point from a List.

Im trying to print the first string at the first X and Y coordinate, second string at the second x and y coordinate and so on. But i'm unable to figure out how to do it. I tried it using the below code, but it draws all the string at each coordinate.

```
   Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

   foreach (var str in outputstring)
    {
      foreach (var xpoint in cofgravX)
       {
        fx = (int)xpoint;

        foreach (var ypoint in cofgravY)
         {
           fy = (int)ypoint;

            listBox2.Items.Add(str);
            string drawString = str.ToString();
            Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
            SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            PointF drawPoint = new PointF(fx, fy);
            g.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);

          }
        }

     }
```

Comment: you only ever reference the 1 string, it will be constant for all points

Comment: Side note: Since `Font` and `Brush` are `IDisposable`, you should wrap them in `using` (in order to release `HFont` and `HBrush` resources)

Comment: Look at the loops - for every string you're writing every point. You'll need to somehow pair each string with a point.

Comment: The use of `CreateGraphics()` is almost never the right approach either.  When the PIctureBox refreshes (minimize then restore the Form for instance), your drawing will be erased.  Instead, use the supplied `e.Graphics` in the [Paint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?view=netframework-4.7.2) event of the PictureBox.

Comment: `var smallestCount = Math.Min(outputstring.Count, Math.Min(cofgravX.Count, cofgravY.Count)); for(int index = 0; index < smallestCount; index++) { var drawstring = outputstring[index]; var drawPoint = new PointF(cofgravX[index], cofgravY[index]); }`

Comment: @Idle_Mind Hi yes I did knew that. I'm executing this through a button for testing, hence this approach. And yes, it does gets erased when the picturebox refreshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to nest your loops. Instead you need to loop once and then grab from each collection the desired object. This can either be done by using a for loop and the index operator or by using `.Zip()` for the LINQish style.

```
var outputstring = new List<string> { "Hello", "World" };
var cofgravX = new List<int> { 5, 20 };
var cofgravY = new List<int> { 5, 20 };

// As for loop
for (int i = 0; i < outputstring.Count; i++)
{
    var message = outputstring[i];
    var fx = cofgravX[i]; // This could throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    var fy = cofgravY[i]; // This could throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException

    // ToDo: Draw on graphics object
}


// LINQish way
var items = cofgravX
    .Zip(cofgravY, (X, Y) => new { X, Y })
    .Zip(outputstring, (Position, Message) => new { Position, Message });

// This will iterate as long as the shortest sequence of all three collection.
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var message = item.Message;
    var fx = item.Position.X;
    var fy = item.Position.Y;

    // ToDo: Draw on graphics object
}
```

Comment: Hi, I get this error message : Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'

Comment: @Roshan: It seems that your *source* is not a list, but an enumerable. In that case you should use the LINQish style method.

Comment: Hi, I had ordered the list using linq hence the error. Problem is, your Linq method works If I remove the code to order the list, But  then the drawings are not in the order I want. This is how I order my string list : var orderedResult =
                outputstring.Batch(n)
                    .Select(b => b.OrderBy(i => i))
                    .SelectMany(x => x);

Comment: @Roshan: The method doesn't care if the outputstring is ordered or not. As long it is an IEnumerable it will zip it up with the coordinates. Did you change in the above code `.Zip(outputstring, ...)`to `.Zip(orderedResult, ...)`? Also, do you have as many x and y coordinates as messages available?

Comment: Also, if you like the for loop style, you could do `var orderedResult = outputstring.Batch(n).....ToList()` to materialize a list that supports the index operator.